# Calling function without declaring class

Tags: c++

I want to achieve the "this line" in the following code. The most logical way is to set GetDog static, but then I cannot use "this". Is there a way to get around it? (not, since I was trying it out, there several lines not relevant to the question)

```
#include <iostream>

class Dog
{
public:
    static int a;
    Dog& GetDog(int k)
    {
        this->a = k;
        return *this;
    }
    int bark()
    {
        return a*a;
    }
};

int Dog::a=0;

int main()
{
    Dog puppy;
    int i = puppy.GetDog(4).bark();
    cout<<i<<endl;
    cout<<Dog::a<<endl;
    //i = Dog::GetDog(6).bark();                 //this line
    return 0;
}
```

Not that doing this has much advantage (just that declaring a class is not required),  but i saw it's used in some package I am using. I kind of want to understand how it is done.

```
class EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW
{
    public:
    static EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW& GetFFT(size_t length);
    virtual void PerformFFT(const EXODoubleWaveform& aWaveform, EXOWaveformFT& aWaveformFT);
...
int main()
{
    EXODoubleWaveform doublewf;
    EXOWaveformFT wfFT;
    ...
    EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW::GetFFT(doublewf.GetLength()).PerformFFT(doublewf,wfFT);
...
```

This static function usage also appears in Geant4, which probably is written by physicists, and so they might not do the wisest thing in programming. I still want to want if doing so has other advantages though.

From the vote down before I can see that this probably is not a regular method as I thought it is. Please comment so before doing it.

Comment: Your title says C (why), but you tagged it C++ and use C++.

Comment: What is `C:` means in your function title

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Which class do you think is not declared?  `EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW` is a declared class in the provided code, but it is not an _instantiated_ class.  No objects of type `EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW` exist at run-time, and that's perfectly fine, because you don't need an object of that type to call the static function `GetFFT`.  That all checks out, but the part that concerns me is that the calling code ignores the returned `EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW&` from `GetFFT`.  Ignoring a returned reference is bad mojo....

Comment: By using this method, I don't really think "not" ignoring the returned  is possible. And I haven't see any guide line about deleting the reference in the package description (yet the FFTW function does NOT have constructors, I cannot help but follow their ideas).

Comment: `EXO...::GetFFT(...)` is probably accessing global or statics, else it does not make sense

Comment: My bad, for the confusion of saying there isn't a constructor. The constructor is protected. I think that can solve the question if I can replace "this" with an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is an implementation of the *Meyers singleton*.

I explain :

In the example given, the class `EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW` does not seem to have a constructor but return a reference to a `EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW` object.

And it looks like this implementation :

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& Instance()
    {
        static Singleton obj;
        return obj;
    }

private:
    Singleton();
};
```

From [this book from **Andrei Alexandrescu**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design), it is said :

> This simple and elegant implementation was first published by **Scott Meyers**; therefore, we'll refer to it as the *Meyers Singleton*.
>
> The Meyers singleton relies on some compiler magic. A function-static object is initialized when the control flow is first passing its definition. Don't confuse static variables that are initialized at runtime[...]
>
> [...]
>
> In addition, the compiler generates code so that after initialization, the runtime support registers the variable for destruction.

So it good to use static to call a method from a class **not instantiated** but don't do it if it is not necessary... Here to represent a *Singleton Pattern* you have to.

But now if you want your class `Dog` look like that :

```
class Dog
{
public:
    static Dog& GetDog(int k)
    {
        static Dog obj( k );
        return obj;
    }
    int bark()
    {
        return a*a;
    }
private:
    int a;
    Dog( int iA ) : a( iA ) {}
};
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated since the `Get` functions have parameters.  I probably wouldn't want `GetDog(1)` and `GetDog(2)` to refer to the same object...

Comment: @aschepler If you look at this example found on the web (https://gist.github.com/mgmarino/3816940), I still think that `EXOFastFourierTransformFFTW` is a singleton (at least it looks like...). Passing an argument to the `GetFFT` is not a good idea, even a bad idea for understanding but...

Comment: I feel like the reference is deleted after PerformFFT, but I am not sure if it's possible.

Comment: @Rabbitybunny If you look closer at the example given in my previous comment, he reuses the object after `PerformFTT`, he uses `PerformInverseFTT`... So I don't think that `PerformFTT` destroy the object or something...

Answer (score 0):

The `static` function usage is correct - it lets you use functions from classes without having an instance of the class. The FFT example you gave probably creates an instance within the static function. So in your case, you would instantiate `Dog` within the `GetDog` function (just be careful with returning references to local variables!).

Comment: If the static function created an instance, returning by reference would probably be a bad thing...

Comment: That's why I mentioned being careful with returning references - if you instantiated via `new`, I think you could get away with it

Comment: Indeed, but then who deletes it, and when?  `T &t = T::getT(42); ...; delete &t;` is not pleasant code...

Comment: In that case, just return a copy (i.e. without the `&` reference).

Comment: It could be the class has a static vector of instances, and `T::getT(number)` gets the instance at that index

Comment: Using static for GetDog will disable the use of "this". I am not sure how else it is going to return it's own class.

Comment: Instead of using `this`, you would just use the newly created instance.

Comment: Inside the function you meant? Is that even possible? I think a lot of things would mess up because of the recursive structure. And I tried Dog mydog; to meet "incomplete type"; Dog *mydog = new Dog(); to meet "new cannot appear in constant expression".

Answer (score 0):

You say that you can't use `this` if you make it `static`, which is true. But why would you want to access it without using an Object instance if you're going to need to use `this` at some point in the future? If it has a default value, or something like that, you could declare that elsewhere outside of the function as `public static` and then access it that way. If you clarify a little bit more as to what you're doing, I'll edit/remove this answer accordingly.

Comment: I think the case is that "the code writer" does not want too many classes declared (the "instance" I suppose) in main, if such a class works exactly like a global function. And because FFTW comes from an external package, "public static" may not be ideal. (I kind of think they probably can use namespace, but I am not familiar with that)

Comment: @Rabbitybunny Namespaces would work too I think. I'm no expert on C/C++ but I thought I'd throw in my two cents as to what would work.

Comment: Yes, but the FFTW function package "achieved" so without using namespace as well as global static. Hence, I am trying to figure out the "this" problem within the function. I tried to declare Dog class variable in the function, could not get it work though.